# Developing Shaders With SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I've read that some of the downfalls of SpriteKit is that you're unable to develop shaders if you use it.

However, I read a post here on SO that suggest otherwise:
[How to apply full-screen SKEffectNode for post-processing in SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937461/how-to-apply-full-screen-skeffectnode-for-post-processing-in-spritekit)

Can you develop your own shaders if you decide to use SpriteKit?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It is not supported in iOS 7, but iOS 8 *will* support custom shaders. For more information, view the [pre-release documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShader_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKShader) of SKShader.

> An SKShader object holds a custom OpenGL ES fragment shader. Shader objects are used to customize the drawing behavior of many different kinds of nodes in Sprite Kit.

Comment: I was not able to find working example code for a SpriteKit shader, so I created this small example and put it on github. https://github.com/mdejong/SKShaderBWWindow/

Answer (score 1):

Sprite Kit does not provide an interface for using custom OpenGL shaders. The `SKEffectNode` class lets you use Core Image filters to post-process parts of a Sprite Kit scene, though. Core Image provides a number of built-in filters that might do some of what you're after, and on OS X you can create custom filter kernels using a language similar to GLSL.