# Add a UIImage as a child to an SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimage, sprite-kit

I'm trying to take a screen shot of my current `SKScene` and apply filters to it as a background element when a message box pops in my game. I think this is the most efficient way to do this...

1. Take screen shot of the current app state
2. Pass this to my message box class
3. Run blur filters, darken it
4. Add it (as a texture or image) behind my my message box layer and over the current contents of the app
5. draw the message on top of it

I know there is a `UIView` method - `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` that will capture the contents of the `UIView` with my `SKScene` in it - but how would I convert the resulting `UIImage` into something I can use in `SpriteKit`? I really don't need the whole `UIView`, just my current `SKScene`.

Appreciate any tips or feedback about what I'm doing. Thanks!

Comment: have you considered using SKEffectNode to blur the scene for you?

Comment: No ... I don't know how to get the UIView added as a child to my SKSpriteNode...

Comment: you can't add a uiview to a node, only another view (the skview). But it sounds like your effect can be done entirely with effect node to create a fullscreen blur, then overlay a transparent msg box by adding it to skview.

Comment: Agree - but this post says the performance is poor - but I'll give it a go on Monday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937461/how-to-apply-full-screen-skeffectnode-for-post-processing-in-spritekit

Comment: how would you apply the blur effect? With a CIFilter, same as effect node uses. It won't be superfast either way.

Comment: I'm not sure! :) I'm still learning ... haven't gotten that far yet